# Labels covered by TabBar using Autolayout

Tags: ios, constraints, ios7

I am making an App using `TabBarController` and AutoLayout.

Whenever I compile the App either on Simulator or on the Device the lower labels, buttons and other views are covered by the `TabBar`. The `views` have constraints so that they would stick to the top and bottom and a `View` (i.e. `MapView`) would stretch.

The case that the views would slip under the TabBar happens only in iOS 7 but not in iOS 6.1 and lower. Any ideas or is it just a bug in the compiler?

Comment: I have similar problem with my app, so I had to turn off autolayout and do frames manually :( I guess maybe it has something to do, with project created in xcode4.x where it had old tab bar, nav bars etc..

Comment: I tried to make the same view in Xcode5 from scratch, but it resulted in the same problem. The problem is only on iOS 7 (3.5" and 4") but not in iOS6 (3.5" and 4").

Comment: and do you have autolayout enabled? Try disabling it and see if it works.

Comment: I do have autolayout enabled. I tried it with having them disabled, then the Views look odd when running the app with a 4" device (with empty space on the bottom)!

Comment: I'm asking because when I used autolayout I accidentaly added constraints to the bottom of my screen so it got resized and unable to scroll (because scroll view got resized to my screen size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found one solution (although it is not what autolayout is supposed to be):

I added the constraint with the |- + -| on the bottom of the storyboard window. In the big cross I added the bottom constraint with a fixed length to `view`instead of `bottom layout guide`and used the current distance (in my case 57).

With this way the `Buttons` and `scrollViews` stay at away from the `TabBar` and don't disappear anymore.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue. Did you report the bug to Apple?

Comment: I submitted a bug report to Apple

Comment: Actually, I fixed my problem by reading this guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html - I had Extend Edges>Under Bottom Bars setting checked in Interface Builder. Unchecking that setting fixed things for me!

Comment: Good hack, but I think Steve's answer (and Sam's comment) is more correct.

Answer (score 6):

The correct answer is to undo Extend Edges either programmatically or through the right panel on a view controller. Click on your view controller and uncheck "Under bottom bars":

[image]